# Sql query join and aggragation at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Select the Sum of the ProjectPossibilityRatio column from the ProjectCompletion table given the ProjectID? I couldnt find sum:

```
SELECT pp.ProjectID,
   pp.ProjectAlias,
   Sum(pd.projectpossibilityratio)
FROM   project pp
   INNER JOIN projectcompletion pc
     ON pp.projectId = pc.projectID
   JOIN projectprocedure pd
     ON pd.projectprocedureID = pc.projectprocedureID
GROUP  BY pd.projectpossibilityratio
```

Here are the table definitions:

```
Create TABLE ProjectType(
ProjectTypeID int identity(1,1),
ProjectTypeName nvarchar(100),
Description nvarchar(200),
primary key(ProjectTypeID)
)


CREATE TABLE Project(
ProjectID int identity(1,1),
ProjectAlias nvarchar(100),
ProjectTypeID int foreign key references ProjectType(ProjectTypeID),
MandatedCompanyID int foreign key references Company(CompanyID),
Iscurrent bit,
BuySide bit,
TeamID int foreign key references WorkTeam(TeamID),
ProjectTurnOver varchar(100),
ProjectStartDate Datetime
primary key(ProjectID))



CREATE TABLE ProjectProcedure(
ProjectProcedureID int identity(1,1),
ProjectProcedureName nvarchar(100),
ProjectProcedureDescription nvarchar(200),
ProjectType int foreign key references ProjectType(ProjectTypeID),
ProjectProcedurePosition int,
ProjectProcedureTime smallint,
ProjectPossibilityRatio int,
Primary Key(ProjectProcedureID))

CREATE TABLE ProjectCompletion(
ProjectID int foreign key references Project(ProjectID),
ProjectProcedureID int foreign key references ProjectProcedure(ProjectProcedureID),
StartDate Datetime,
IsCompletedDate Datetime
Primary Key(ProjectID,ProjectProcedureID)
)
```

Comment: The answer is straight forward, but 0 accepts out of 7 questions stops me bothering.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT pp.ProjectID,pp.ProjectAlias,Sum(pd.projectpossibilityratio)
    FROM project pp INNER JOIN projectcompletion pc ON pp.projectId=pc.projectID 
    JOIN projectprocedure pd ON pd.projectprocedureID=pc.projectprocedureID 
    GROUP BY pp.ProjectID,pp.ProjectAlias
```

And I agree with LeftyX, you should go back and accept answers

Comment: i did now.I'm sorry i was working without sleep i forgot to do that.thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Add all the column names that you are selecting to the group by list.